# Display a long message in desired format using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html-lists

I have long message string. Each parent message is separated by a symbol `#` and child message separated by a symbol `^`.

```
$scope.messages = "Message1#Message2#Message3#Message4^Message41^Message42#Message5^Message51^Message52^Message53^Message54^Message55";
```

I want to display these messages in an **unordered list** format like below.

[image]

I used `ng-repeat` with `ul-li` to show the messages but the child messages are not properly aligned as nested `ul-li` elements and also show repeated messages.

```html
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="message in messages.split('#')">
        {{message}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="msg in message.split('^')">
                {{msg}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But this code doesn't show the desired output. My effort resides [here](https://jsfiddle.net/va94nqvd/1/).

Comment: Hi MAC. Editors tend to [trim chatty material](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776/472495) here, to make posts easier to read; [see also here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288160/472495). Material that might be interpreted as pleading is also good to remove, [since that may protect the question from a poor reception](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366264/472495). If you see edits that you don't understand, you can always ping the editor - I am reachable on posts I edit via `@halfer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost done it, check out some modifications:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.messages = "Message1#Message2#Message3#Message4^Message41^Message42#Message5^Message51^Message52^Message53^Message54^Message55";
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<ul ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <li ng-repeat="message in messages.split('#')">    
    {{message.split('^')[0]}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="msg in message.split('^').splice(1)">
        {{msg}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is most convincing solution. Thanks @Slava

Answer (score 2):

Its better to convert the string into an object beforehand. I've tried to convert it into an object form so that it becomes easier for the template to read and conditionally show the parent-children relationship.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.messages = "Message1#Message2#Message3#Message4^Message41^Message42#Message5^Message51^Message52^Message53^Message54^Message55";

    $scope.messages = $scope.messages
      .split("#").reduce((acc, item) => {
        if (item.includes('^')) {
          let c = item.split('^');
          acc[c[0]] = c.slice(1, -1);
        } else {
          acc[item] = null;
        }

        return acc;
      }, {});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in messages">
      {{key}}
      
      <ul ng-if="value">
        <li ng-repeat="child in value track by $index">
          {{child}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! If you run this code snippet, you will see the different output. Seems like you didn't check. This code even losses information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @31piy. This solution too works well. +1 for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what are you looking for

```
<li ng-repeat="message in messages">
            {{message.text}}
                <ul>
                  <li ng-if="message.sub" ng-repeat="msg in message.sub">
                    {{msg}}

                  </li>
                </ul>
          </li>

$scope.myFilter = function(input){
            if(typeof input == 'string'){
                var result = [];
                var items = input.split('#');
                for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
                    var item = items[i];
                    if(item.indexOf('^') == -1){//item doesn't have '^' means parent message
                        result.push({text:item});
                    }else{
                        //here my logic goes wrong to split child messages
                        var subItems = item.split('^');
                        //now If I push this subItems directly into result, not a good idea

                        result.push({sub: subItems.splice(1, subItems.length), text: subItems[0]});
                    }
                }
                return result;
            }
            return [];
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/va94nqvd/12/

Comment: Thanks, Tan Duong! This answer losses information if you check the output in jsfiddle.